# using assert on different datatypes for API testing

Tags: python, api, assert

I have 2 sets of data one returned from database and one from API response.
One returned from database is a list of tuples (variable Db).
One returned from API response is a list of dictionary  (variable Api)

Is there a way to check if each tuple element in Db matches dictionary element in Api. I tried through multiple for loops but it did not work.
I would like to know if there is an elegant way (may be assert) to do this.

```
Db=[('D967E735-070D-48F9-A3BB-D00766D39F57', 'test1', '51-00401'),
    ('94F903D1-2EE7-4BD2-A0C6-B464D9F2939C', 'test4', '51-00404'),
    ('FE0CC34C-BA6A-4123-B72C-617ADC0A93E7', 'test10', '51-00409')]

Api=[{'Id': 'd967e735-070d-48f9-a3bb-d00766d39f57',
  'name': 'test1',
  'Number': '51-00401'},
 {'Id': '94f903d1-2ee7-4bd2-a0c6-b464d9f2939c',
  'name': 'test4',
  'Number': '51-00404'},
 {'Id': 'fe0cc34c-ba6a-4123-b72c-617adc0a93e7',
  'name': 'test10',
  'Number': '51-00409'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
Db = [('D967E735-070D-48F9-A3BB-D00766D39F57', 'test1', '51-00401'),
      ('94F903D1-2EE7-4BD2-A0C6-B464D9F2939C', 'test4', '51-00404'),
      ('FE0CC34C-BA6A-4123-B72C-617ADC0A93E7', 'test10', '51-00409')]

Api = [{'Id': 'd967e735-070d-48f9-a3bb-d00766d39f57', 'name': 'test1', 'Number': '51-00401'},
       {'Id': '94f903d1-2ee7-4bd2-a0c6-b464d9f2939c', 'name': 'test4', 'Number': '51-00404'},
       {'Id': 'fe0cc34c-ba6a-4123-b72c-617adc0a93e7', 'name': 'test10', 'Number': '51-00409'}]

for i in Db:
    match = i[0].lower() in {d['Id'].lower() for d in Api}
    print(i[0], match)

# D967E735-070D-48F9-A3BB-D00766D39F57 True
# 94F903D1-2EE7-4BD2-A0C6-B464D9F2939C True
# FE0CC34C-BA6A-4123-B72C-617ADC0A93E7 True
```

Comment: Thanks jp_data_analysis. I used your solution and expanded it to test 'name' and 'Number as below. How can I use asset?? 
for dbitems in Db:
    matchid=dbitems[0].lower() in {Apiitems['Id'].lower() for Apiitems in Api}
    matchname=dbitems[1] in {Apiitems['name'] for Apiitems in Api}
    matchnumber=dbitems[2] in {Apiitems['Number'] for Apiitems in Api}

Comment: @Sel_Python, sorry I can't read your code, or understand what you mean. What is asset? Feel free to ask a new question if this specific answer doesn't help.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say 'assert'. I am not able to figure out a way to show my code in a readable format. selecting my code and pressing 'ctrl+K' and saving is not working in the comment. 

    for dbitems in Db:
        matchid=dbitems[0].lower() in {Apiitems['Id'].lower() for Apiitems in 
        Api}
        matchname=dbitems[1] in {Apiitems['name'] for Apiitems in Api}
       matchnumber=dbitems[2] in {Apiitems['Number'] for Apiitems in Api}


    assert all(matchid==matchname==matchnumber), print ("DB Values 
    and API values matched")

Comment: @Sel_Python, have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting